# SQL - Users in multiple user groups returning the same user more than once

Tags: mysql

Okay so I have four tables: `users`, `groups`, `usergroups`, and  `workloadtracker`. As you can imagine, `usergroups` is my "through" table between `users` and `groups`. `workloadtracker` is just a table that has `user_id`'s and keeps track of workloads.

I have the following sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*,ug.*,w.*
FROM users as u 
LEFT JOIN users_groups as ug ON u.id = ug.user_id 
JOIN workloadtracker as w ON u.id = w.userid 
WHERE w.crmid is not null
      and ug.group_id != 2
      and ug.group_id != 1
      and ug.group_id != 7
      and ug.group_id != 17
      and ug.group_id != 21
      and ug.group_id != 22
order by w.points desc
```

This gets me the information I want.....the workload of users in certain groups.....but if a user is in more than one group he shows up more than once. How can I stop this?

Comment: if the user belongs to more than one group then, what do you *want* to happen?  Only show the first group the user belongs to?  What constitutes the "first" group?  You need to think about what you need before we can help solve your problem I think.

Comment: I'm sure that the DISTINCT operator has no effect on this query. Instead, if you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Additionally, your question states there are 4 tables, but only 3 are involved in the query.  In your query you are selecting * from your ug alias... do you ***actually need*** the information returned from ug?  depending on the nature of what you're doing with, and what data you need, you might be able to just drop the ug.* from the query to get your desired results.

Comment: The query as written doesn't do what you say it does ("This gets me the information i want.....the workload of users in certain groups").  Since you are using LEFT JOIN for users_groups, this query actually returns the workload of all users regardless of user_group, but also repeats users that are in multiple groups.  It's not clear what you want.  If you want all users, you don't need to join with user_group.  If you only want specific groups, then you probably want INNER JOIN with GROUP BY.

Comment: Okay so first off this is not MY query lol. I am maintaining another developers code and the code is so ridiculously spaghetti that im afraid to make any unnecessary changes in fear that they are actually using it somewhere...thus why i didn't remove their DISTINCT OR the ug.*...in fact im pretty sure it doesn't need u.* or w.* and I could easily specify the columns but that would require me going through all 3 million + lines of code to determine where / if its being used and which rows are needed. No thanks

Comment: cbranch.....your actually very correct. In fact I believe that is the answer. I need to REMOVE the users_groups join because i only need the workload stats for each user once....i don't need them repeated for every group they are in.

Comment: I apologize....answer below is correct.....my question isn't as clear as I would normally make it since I didn't fully understand the query because I didn't write it. Now all is clear and an answer has been given :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DISTINCT is not restricting your results to single instances of users because you are including all fields from users_groups.

There are multiple records in users_groups for a user that is in multiple groups, so your query returns multiple DISTINCT records for those users.

The quick solution would be to remove 'ug.*' from your SELECT clause.

EDIT:
If you need some info on the group/groups the users are in, you can use a GROUP BY clause with an aggregate function.
For example, the number of groups they are in:

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.*,w.*,COUNT(ug.group_id) AS num_groups
FROM users as u 
LEFT JOIN users_groups as ug ON u.id = ug.user_id 
JOIN workloadtracker as w ON u.id = w.userid 
WHERE w.crmid is not null
      and ug.group_id != 2
      and ug.group_id != 1
      and ug.group_id != 7
      and ug.group_id != 17
      and ug.group_id != 21
      and ug.group_id != 22
GROUP BY u.id
order by w.points desc
```

Comment: This is in fact correct. At FIRST I thought that removing the join was the way to go but then I realized that the purpose of the join (i didn't write this) was to remove users that were in certain groups. So I had to leave it in. Removing ug.* did in fact work.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the list of groups, use aggregation:

```
SELECT u.*, w.*, group_concat(ug.group_id) as groups
FROM users au JOIN
     workloadtracker w
     ON u.id = w.userid LEFT JOIN
     users_groups ug
     ON u.id = ug.user_id and
        ug.group_id not in (2, 1, 7, 17, 21, 22)
WHERE w.crmid is not null
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY w.points desc;
```

Some notes:

- I moved the `JOIN` before the `LEFT JOIN`.  This is a convention.  It makes it easier to see which join's are filtering the initial data (and it prevents certain types of errors).
- I changed the condition on `group_id` to use `not in`.
- I moved that condition to the `on` clause.  Otherwise, the `left join` is turned into an `inner join`.
- This assumes that the `w` table does not have multiple rows for each user.  Otherwise, you might want to aggregate columns from that table as well.

Comment: whats with the random "J" character after the NOT IN ?

Comment: @BillGarrison . . . That would have been a typo.